# Google Apps Script - Gmail - Is it possible to forward a message as an attachment?

Tags: google-apps-script

With the Google Apps Script Google Workspace services is it possible to forward a message as an attachment rather than just the normal forward as described here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forwardrecipient?

Edit: I need this to work on the currently viewed message. Something similar to this:

```
function onGmailMessageOpen(e) {
  const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.messageMetadata.messageId);
  message.forward("abc@def.com");
}
```

where `onGmailMessageOpen` is the contextualTrigger function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't directly forward a message as attachment by using Google Apps Script only

As a workaround I suggest you to use extra services and the following code:

```
function forwardAsAttachment() {
  var messageRaw = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("email@example.com", "IDexample", {format: "raw"});

  var message = Utilities.newBlob(messageRaw.raw, "message/rfc822", "Subject");
  
  MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com", "Title", "Body", {
    attachments: [message]
  });
}
```

First of all I added the Gmail API service into the project and retrieved the desired message in order to get the RAW message.

Then I created a Blob formatted as RFC822 which is the raw message expected by the service and then sent the message formatted and [base64URL encoded](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format).

### References

- [Gmail API in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)
- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)